# Showing and hiding Objects

Tags: excel, vba

I was hopping someone could guide me into the right direction here. I have a 3 objects that I want to disappear when the "White" is selected from the dropdown otherwise to stay visible.  So far I got this:

```
 Dim Wc As Worksheet
    Set Wc = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim MyArray(1 To 3) As Range
    Dim SCC As String

    Set MyArray(1) = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Object01")
    Set MyArray(2) = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Object02")
    Set MyArray(3) = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Object03")

    SCC = MyArray

    If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("MyRange").Value = "White" Then
        ws.Shapes(SCC).Visible = False
    Else
        ws.Shapes(SCC).Visible = True
    End If
```

Any ideas why it's not working? Any suggestions more then welcome

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your "Objects"? Is it simply an Array of text/values stored in a range of cells?

Comment: It's a literally an shape objects inserted into excel sheet to hide / unhide fields when certain conditions are met

Comment: Thanks for explaining. GSerg's solution (posted below) is all you need. Just remember to adjust your code to do `Dim ws as Worksheet` // `Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")`, as you are referring `ws` in your code instead of `Wc`.

Comment: You need to specify what element (index) in the array should be used by `SCC`. `SCC = MyArray(1)` for example.

Answer (score 2):

```vb
Dim SCC() As Variant
SCC = Array("Object01", "Object02", "Object03")

wc.Shapes.Range(SCC).Visible = False
```

Comment: Not sure why you got "-1", I confirm that the solution works nicely on my side.

Comment: Nice solution. I didn't know that `Shapes` could be passed an array like that.

Comment: Just replace, please, `Me` with `ActiveSheet` and it works (for shapes on a sheet) as desired...